# How to use HTML field name in javascript if the field name contains a "." (dot)?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button, stripes

I am using   `<detail:form>` and `<tags:field >` in my jsp page. I tried to see the source code the browser generates using firebug and it showed to me that the form name is "**checkForm**" and all of the field names has **"check."** as a prefix. So one of the field's (it is a radio button) name is `check.isEndorseByApplicant` .

What I am trying to achieve is, when a some element in a drop down menu is selected, I wanted to change the radio button from yes to no. The problem is since the field contains dot in its name, I can't do that. i.e **document.checkForm.check.isEndorseByApplicant** is not working for me. There is no way I can take out the dot from the field's name at this time. Any ideas?

```
            function autoSelect(checkEndorsement)
            {
            alert(document.checkForm.check.isEndorseByApplicant)
                if(checkEndorsement.value=="Student")
                    check.isEndorsedBy[0].checked=true;
                else
                    check.isEndorsedBy[1].checked=true;
            }


        </html:javascript>
```

.
.
.

```
<detail:form object="check" >
```

.
.
.
.

```
<td><tags:field property="isEndorseByApplicant" onclick="autoSelect(this.form);"  /></td>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `document.checkForm.elements['check.isEndorseByApplicant']`

Comment: That's awesome. Many thanks. Btw, that's why I love stackoverflow. :P